# Use HTTP_Request response content

Tags: php, json, http-request

I have an `HTTP_Request2_Response` variable which when I echo using `$response->getBody()`  gives me this:

```
{"results":["element1","element2","element3"],"id":"elementID"}
```

Is there any way to get each element like `$respons["id"]`? Is there any way to convert these results into a json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely. `json_decode()` is the function you're looking for:

```
<?php

$str = "{\"results\":[\"element1\",\"element2\",\"element3\"],\"id\":\"elementID\"}";

$obj = json_decode($str);

print_r($obj);

?>
```

Produces:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => element1
            [1] => element2
            [2] => element3
        )

    [id] => elementID
)
```

Since it gets returned as an object, you can access the elements as public members. In other words: `$obj->id` will give you `'elementID'`.

Or as an array:

```
$array = json_decode($str, true);

print_r($array);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => element1
            [1] => element2
            [2] => element3
        )

    [id] => elementID
)
```

`echo $array['id'];` gives `elementID`.

Comment: Thanks very much , but what if the number of elements (element1,element2,...) isn't known and its count can be different. is there any more flexible way to get them?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. You should handle it the same way you'd handle any other array of unknown length.

Comment: I don't want to manually edit the string and then get its json file, I want to define a pattern for example define that I have values for "results" and "id" and then get their values with something like results[0]

Comment: There is no manual editing of any strings. I included the string as a demonstration of how the function works. You'd use this: `json_decode($response->getBody())`, and treat is as an object (or array, with the extra argument).